# Unwanted border-radius artefact with box-shadow spread

Tags: css

Goal is a borderless circle with a soft edge, containing text or other elements. How do I get rid of the thin black border line in the following example? I've tried adding a border with the same or transparent color. It can be done with 1px x 1px and large spread, but I want to put stuff inside.

```css
body { background: black; }
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px white;

}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

Comment: I am not seeing a border in Chrome 87 on Windows 10.

Comment: I saw it in all the standard Mac browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it with a `radial-gradient()`

```css
body { background: black; }
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-side,white calc(100% - 15px),transparent );
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I did play around with radial gradients, but couldn't get exactly what I wanted. Also, didn't know you could do calc() inside like that.